# Office word 2010 history/activity

Tags: macos, ms-office, microsoft

I was curious if Word 2010 for Mac has a activity/history viewer for what there has been written/deleted in the document, like Google Docs has?
So far I have not found anything, not even on the web (Googled it).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you're talking about tracked changes.

You can access this via MS Word's Tools menu: **Tools > Track Changes > Highlight Changes...**

Comment: This has been available in [Word since at least 2004](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=412916&seqNum=6)